# Having trouble reassigning indice of matrice to a new value

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
function[x] = change(matrix)

matrix(2,2) = 2;

end
```

I was wondering why whenever I run this function the element at row 2, column 2, is not getting reassigned to the value of 2 I assigned in the function. Also, I get a warning saying "the value assigned to matrix may be unused." Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You need to return the modified `matrix`: `function matrix = change(matrix)`

Comment: maybe take a look at the [documentation about functions](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)

Comment: Is it possible to mutate the matrix without adding it to the output portion of the function?